# How to count rows from multiple tables in one single sql query

Tags: mysql

I've a issue where have to fetch row counts from multiple tables with where in it.

eg:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 where condition;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 where condition;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 where condition;
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2;
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 where condition;
```

You can add extra field to find which row you get by following query

```
SELECT "COND-1" AS TITLE, COUNT(*) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT "COND-2" AS TITLE, COUNT(*) FROM table1 where condition;
UNION
SELECT "COND-3" AS TITLE, COUNT(*) FROM table2;
UNION
SELECT "COND-4" AS TITLE, COUNT(*) FROM table3 where condition;
```